# Can't find Zend directory in EasyPHP folder

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I'm about reading a tutorial about creating php extensions in C. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and EasyPHP whose directory includes /ext folder (PHP extensions directory)

this is the tutorial : http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Developing-Custom-PHP-Extensions-Part-1/2/

I've a problem in the step 4 :

> Blockquote
>   4. In the Preprocessor Category, add the following "Additional include directories": ...., ....\main, ....\Zend, ....\TSRM, ....\bindlib_w32.

I searched the main , zend , tsrm and bindlib_w32 directories in the easyphp forlder and I couldn't find them.

if EasyPHP doesnot include zend directory. How can I deploy it in its correct directory?

and thank you in advance

Comment: Where did you get the other additional libs from?

Comment: there are not libs, but C source code files , you can find em in the php.net website but remember , download the php source code of the same PHP installed in your server (if you 've php 5.3, you download PHP 5.3 source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I've found the solution to my question, I was indeed looking for the zend folder in the directory of php. But I must look in the **PHP code source directory**, not in the php itself. thank you